# R: remove numbers of vector

Tags: r, vector, numbers

I've got the following vector:

```
codes <- c("3WC8" , "456" , "lev", "1")
```

I want to remove `"456"` and `"1"`, but I do NOT want to remove the numbers of `"3WC8"`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `gsub` to remove all the numbers from each element, then `nzchar` to check/keep only the non-zero character elements.

```
codes[nzchar(gsub("[0-9]+", "", codes))]
# [1] "3WC8" "lev"
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
> codes[is.na(sapply(codes, as.numeric))]
[1] "3WC8" "lev"
```

or simply (as suggested by @akrun in comments):

```
> codes[is.na(as.numeric(codes))]
[1] "3WC8" "lev"
```

Ignore the warnings in both codes.

Answer (score 3):

Or you could do:

```
grep("^\\d+$", codes, value=TRUE, invert=TRUE)
#[1] "3WC8" "lev"
```